# Use keyboard shortcuts from IntelliJ in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to know if it´s possible to import keymap from IntelliJ or PHPStorm to Visual Studio. I´m used to working with IntelliJ IDE´s. Now I´m starting to develop some apps in .NET and it´s kinda hard to get used to the new key schemes.

Comment: I know it's possible with Resharper by IntelliJ

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Remark:** This answer is four years old and a bit outdated. If you don't want to install ReSharper just to get the keymap, the other answers describe ways via (free) VS plugins.

The easiest way is probably to install [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) (by the same company that does IntelliJ), which gives you a choice to use the IntelliJ keyboard layout. Otherwise you'd have to find an exported settings file for Visual Studio which includes the already changed shortcuts, but I couldn't find any in a quick Google search.

[image]

You could apply the shortcuts with ReSharper, export your keyboard settings (Tools => Import and Export Settings), uninstall (or disable) ReSharper and re-import the files if necessary.

Comment: The solution below is much better and this solution should be updated! It references to a paid 3rd party plugin - just to use a build in feature.

Comment: @Bjego IIRC, the IntelliJ keymap is fairly new and didn't exist back then (this answer is almost 4 years old!). Since it still works (and the supplied IntellJ keymap is different from the one R# uses), and the other answers detail the newer/free/better solutions, I'm not sure what I should change in this answer.

Comment: sounds okay for me. But maybe you could add a hint that there is a plugin free solution these days. To make it more obvious that this was the right solution 4 years ago :)

Comment: I think the solution bellow by @mrsrinivas should be the correct one as it is free, easy to install and just works.

Answer (score 41):

> Be advised, **Resharper is not free**.

I am using this plug-in [Hot Keys 2017 - Keyboard Shortcuts](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JustinClareburtMSFT.HotKeys)

Choose IntelliJ IDEA Style for C# from Tools > Options > Keyboard and you will have IntelliJ shortcuts in Visual Studio 2017.

For Visual Studio 2015 there is a different plug-in

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JustinClareburtMSFT.HotKeys-KeyboardShortcuts

I didn't use it so not sure if it works as expected

Answer (score 39):

> Adding to **wise answer from [Adil H. Raza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5002600/adil-h-raza)**

After Download and Install [Hot Keys 2017 - Keyboard Shortcuts](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JustinClareburtMSFT.HotKeys) in your PC, try following these steps to **configure IDEA key-map in Visual studio 2017**

#### 1.Go to options

[image: Goto options]

#### 2. Under Environment -> Keyboard, Pick the keyboard map of your choice

[image: Pick the Keymap of your choice]

#### 3. Finally apply the settings with *OK*

[image: Finally apply the settings]

Comment: I think this is the correct solution, it's easy to install, it works and its also free!

Comment: to date, it does not work

Comment: @EliavLouski: thanks for the comment. I am not using VS any more, could you share the working solution here? It will help others

Comment: i ended up downloading resharper trial

Comment: It's working on  Visual Studio Community 2022 v17.4.3. Tankyou!

Comment: The menu structure changed in VS 2022. It is Tools > Keyboard Shortcuts > ...

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble finding the Intellij keyboard map option in Visual Studio 2017, try this:

1. Go to Tools > Options > Keyboard Shortcuts.
2. Select the "Load Shortcuts" button.
3. Choose "Intellij Idea" from the dropdown menu.

This should allow you to use the Intellij keyboard map in Visual Studio 2017. Please note this only works for Visual Studio 2017 not other editors.

Comment: I said Visual Studio 2017 not VS code.

Comment: right, unable to modify the vote now unless the answer is modified.

Comment: Ok, I edited the main post added "Please note this only works for Visual Studio 2017 not other editors" comment for other people consideration. Now you can  modify the vote.